# Linear operators with "stationary"/"invariant" matrices w.r.t. basis change

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I was going through a lecture about change of basis in a finite dimensional linear space $V$ over $F$ (where $F$ is some number field).

Let $e_1, e_2, \dots e_n$ be the old basis and
$f_1, f_2, \dots f_n$ be the new basis of some finite-dimensional i.e. $n$-dimensional linear/vector space.

Let $A$ be the change-of-basis matrix i.e. $f = A^Te$, where
$e = (e_1, e_2, \dots, e_n)^T$,
$f = (f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n)^T$. This is just a short notation I came up with (I don't even know if it's officially used, since by $f$ and by $e$ I denote here columns of vectors, and not columns of numbers). But I find this notation handy.

So OK... after finishing this lecture, I realized later that if we consider the linear operators $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ whose matrices are $A$ and $A^{-1}$ **in the old basis**, then their matrices do not change when we change the basis i.e. they have the same matrices $A$ and $A^{-1}$ also in the new basis. And since this seems an interesting property to me... I asked myself: are there other such linear operators?

If $\phi : V \to V$ is such operator (whose matrix stays the same when we change the basis), then its matrix  $B$ in the old basis must satisfy the equation $B = A^{-1}BA$ or in other words: $AB = BA$. So... what are these matrices $B$ which commute with $A$? If I know them, I will know all linear operators whose matrices stay the same when we change the basis, right?

Let's assume all matrices here contain just some real numbers
(i.e. let's assume our initial vector space is over the reals),
even though I am curious to know also what happens
when $F$ is some other other number field.

**Note:** I don't know if "linear operator" is the right term in English, I think it's also called "endomorphism". That's what I mean by linear operator here (just a linear map from $V$ to itself).

Comment: Nice question. You located an interesting interpretation of the commutation of two matrices. It's elementary, but I have to admit I never thought at commutation in this way. This gives an explanation of the famous fact that the only matrices that commute with all invertible matrices are scalars. That's clear: scalar operators are the only ones that have the same expression regardless of the basis we choose to represent them as matrices.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro By scalar matrices you mean those of the form $\lambda \cdot I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, right? Yeah, my question is basic indeed, I was just reading a basic lecture about $change\ of\ basis$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro What is the proof for the statement you mentioned? Btw, I am not sure I was asking exactly that. I was more like asking: given A (a fixed invertible matrix which describes that particular change of basis), what are the matrices which commute with that particular A?